# Leaflet: showArea in edit mode

Tags: javascript, leaflet, draw

I am using Leaflet Draw . I start drawing a rectangle with something like this:

```
polygon_options = {
    showArea: true,
    shapeOptions: {
        color: '#ff0000',
    }
}

var rectangleDrawer = new L.Draw.Rectangle(map, polygon_options);
rectangleDrawer.enable();
```

While I draw the new rectangle I can see its area. After it's created I can go to edit mode to modify it. In that mode, it doesn't show the area value. Does anyone know who to make it show the area?

Thanks!

Comment: There is no option in EditPolyOptions for that (see https://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.draw/docs/leaflet-draw-latest.html#editpoly)

Comment: Any ideas on how to do something similar? Thanks!

Comment: 1) git clone https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw/ 2) make the necessary changes to the files like https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw/blob/develop/src/edit/handler/Edit.Poly.js and https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw/blob/develop/src/edit/handler/EditToolbar.Edit.js 3) jake build